# react-navigation - navigating from child component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a leaderboard which calls a component and passes it data to it like so:

```
   _renderItem =({item}) => (
    <childComponent
        key={item._id}
        id={item._id}
        name={item.name}
    />
   );
```

And inside the childComponent I try do this:

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile", { id: this.props.id})} >
       <View>
         <Right>
              {arrowIcon}
         </Right>
       </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Where I am hoping that it will then go to the profile page and grab the correct data based on the id passed to it. The issue is that when I click the arrow to go to the profile page I get the error **Cannot read property 'navigate of undefined**. I have put both the leaderboard and childComponent in my HomeDrawerrRoutes.js and MainStackRouter.js. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: What does ```MainStack``` look like?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have `import Leaderboard from "../components/leaderboard"` `import childComponent from "../components/childComponent"` `export default (StackNav = StackNavigator({
  LeaderBoard: { screen: LeaderBoard },
  childComponent: { screen: childComponent }
}));`

Comment: Hmm even right inside the render I just tryed to console.log(this.props.navigation.state); and it says that it cannot read property of undefined.. So it must be something to do with childComponent?

Comment: ```StackNavigator``` passes the property automatically. Do a console log of props in childComponent's constructor to see what you are getting

Comment: I couldn't see any navigation props being passed after logging it. Is the problem that because childComponent is a child in Leaderboard and Profile is on the same level (routing wise) as Leaderboard. Do I need to add a route for children to go to the parents or something? Am a little lost to be honest

Comment: From your code you have it as a second screen? Are you not navigating to it?

Comment: Second screen? I currently have in the route for the child - childComponent: { screen: Profile }, LeaderBoard: { screen: Profile } which is all in the same Mainstack route

Comment: Give me a sec ... I'll add a simple answer that will clarify things

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a 3 page example that shows how to pass the `navigate` function to a child component and how to customize props send to screens from within the StackNavigator

```
// subcomponent ... receives navigate from parent
const Child = (props) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={() => props.navigate(props.destination) }>
            <Text>{props.text}>>></Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
// receives navigation from StackNavigator
const PageOne = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Page One</Text>
            <Child 
                navigate={props.navigation.navigate} 
                destination="pagetwo" text="To page 2"/>
        </View>
    )
}
// receives custom props AND navigate inside StackNavigator 
const PageTwo = (props) => (
    <View>
        <Text>{props.text}</Text>
        <Child 
            navigate={props.navigation.navigate} 
            destination="pagethree" text="To page 3"/>
    </View>
);
// receives ONLY custom props (no nav sent) inside StackNAvigator
const PageThree = (props) => <View><Text>{props.text}</Text></View>

export default App = StackNavigator({
    pageone: { 
        screen: PageOne, navigationOptions: { title: "One" } },
    pagetwo: { 
        screen: (navigation) => <PageTwo {...navigation} text="Page Deux" />, 
        navigationOptions: { title: "Two" } 
    },
    pagethree: { 
        screen: () => <PageThree text="Page III" />, 
        navigationOptions: { title: "Three" }
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that all up - works like a charm!

Comment: I had similar problems. Glad it helped

Comment: I know... This works, but I believe it is possible do something better

Comment: is this all in one file?

Comment: It would work in a single file but a proper app would have separate files for each page. The key here is how (and where) the navigation prop is used.

Answer (score 36):

There is an easy Solution for this,

use `withNavigation` . it's  a higher order component which passes the navigation prop into a wrapped Component.

example child component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <View
      onPress = {()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('NewComponent')}>
     ... logic
    </View>

  }
}

// withNavigation returns a component that wraps ChildComponent and passes in the
// navigation prop
export default withNavigation(ChildComponent);
```

for more details : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html

Comment: This is the real solution, not the one above.

Comment: how would i do this with redux ?

Answer (score 8):

The `useNavigation` hook was introduced in v5:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export function ChildComponent() => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Back"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation

Answer (score 5):

For some reason if you don't want to use withNavigation, the following solution works too. You just have to pass navigation as a prop to your child component.

For example:

```
export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
      <View>
        <ChildComponent navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

And in child component:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
   return (
       <View>
         <TouchableOpacity 
           onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Wherever you want to navigate')}      
          />
       </View>
      );
    };
export default ChildComponent;
```