# Passing the navigation object down the nested react component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My react component hierarchy looks like

```
StackNavigation
  - MainScreen
      - List
          - Row
              - Button
```

My usecase involves go to a new screen on click of the button. My main screen receives react-navigation's navigation props. How do I pass it down to my button in a sane manner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackNavigator through Component gives undefined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457706/stacknavigator-through-component-gives-undefined-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better pass a callback to your button through all the hierarchy and call it when button is pressed. Afterwards when you know which button is pressed (on which row) you can navigate to necessary screen from your MainScreen.