# Navigation getting undefined while navigating

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate from one component to other. The error I am getting is on press:

> undefined is not an object evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate

*header.js*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Image } from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";


export default class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }



  render() {
    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style = {{ flex: 1 , flexDirection :"row"}} >

        <Icon name="align-justify" size={30} color="#fff" 

        style= {{ paddingLeft : 20, paddingTop:20 , alignSelf: 'flex-start',}}

        onPress = { () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications') }

        />

        <Text style={styles.Text}> {this.props.title} </Text>

        </View>

        </View>

        );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 70,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "#3498db",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  Text: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignSelf: "center",
    paddingLeft: 20
  }
});
```

*navigation.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform} from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons";
import { StackNavigator, NavigationActions, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from '../components/loginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from '../components/registerScreen';
import HomeScreen from "../components/HomeScreen";
import NotificationsScreen from "../components/NotificationsScreen";

const HomeStack = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: { drawerLabel: "Home" }
    },

    Notifications: {
      screen: NotificationsScreen,
      navigationOptions: { drawerLabel: "Notifications" }
    }
  },
  {
    gesturesEnabled: false
  }
);



const MainNavigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
    },
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: { gesturesEnabled: false }
    },
    Register: {
      screen: RegisterScreen,
      navigationOptions: { gesturesEnabled: false }
    }
  },
  {
    transitionConfig: () => ({ screenInterpolator: () => null }),
    headerMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "Login",
    navigationOptions: { gesturesEnabled: false }
  }
);


export default MainNavigation;
```

Comment: I don't see your `Header.js` in any of the `navigation` stacks, therefore there is `no props` for the `navigation` for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackNavigator through Component gives undefined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457706/stacknavigator-through-component-gives-undefined-error)

Answer (score 1):

Only the component you have directly linked to the screen gets `this.props.navigation.navigate`.

the child elements inside the screen doesn't get `this.props.navigation.navigate.`

Let's say you are in HomeScreen. you can use `this.props.navigation` in here. But if you are using Header as child component in HomeScreen then you have to explicitly pass as

`<Header navigation={this.props.navigation} />`.

Answer (score 0):

In which file do you call  MainNavigation?

In order to get the naivagation as a prop you will need wrap you're App component in the MainNavigation Component.
Something like this.

```
<App>
<MainNavigation/>
</App>
```