# React-Native navigation with section list

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have this code in the SectionListView.js:

```
class SectionListItem extends Component {
render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('YoutubeScreen')} underlayColor='transparent'>
            <View style={styles.SectionListItem}>
                <MaterialIcons name='youtube-searched-for' size={20} style={styles.YtIcon}>
                </MaterialIcons>
                <View style={styles.Item}>
                    <Text style={{fontFamily:Fonts.OpenSans}}>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:6,fontFamily:Fonts.OpenSans}}>{this.props.item.details}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.IconContainer}>
                    <MaterialIcons name='chevron-right' size={15} style={styles.IconChevron}>
                    </MaterialIcons>
                </View>
            </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

I want that user clicking on list item, go to YoutubeScreen.
This sectionlist is included in a Source Screen:

```
export default class Source extends Component {
render() {

    return (

        <Container>
            <Header style={styles.Header}>
                <Left>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='menu' onPress={()=>
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}/>
                    </Button>
                </Left>
                <Body style={styles.Body}>
                    <Text style={{color:'#ffffff'}}>Source</Text>
                </Body>
                <Right />
            </Header>
            <Content style={styles.Content}>
                <SectionListView/>
            </Content>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

}

My error is "can`t find navigate variable" in section list.I don`t understand how pass navigation or navigate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackNavigator through Component gives undefined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457706/stacknavigator-through-component-gives-undefined-error)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `navigation` prop in your `component` in order to access it

```
<SectionListView navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

and

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('YoutubeScreen')}
```

or a better way would be to *access the navigation in your parent component*

**SectionListItem.js**

```
onPress={()=>this.props.navigate('YoutubeScreen')}
```

**Source.js**

```
  <SectionListView navigate={this._navigate}/>

  // Outside of render
  _navigate = (screen) => this.props.navigation.navigate(screen)
```