# React Native: Navigation not working in component

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I can not open the third page screen with the On Press method in the List Component.js file. I do not understand the problem. I want to know what I'm doing wrong with this. Where is the problem? Thank you. Please help.

Thank you for your reply but this will not work, my friend. I've updated the ListComponent.js file. The ListComponent.js file is actually a list. Please can you look again. ?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  WebView,
  AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button
} from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import ListComponent from './ListComponent';




 class App extends Component {

  static navigationOptions =
  {
     title: 'App',
  };

  OpenSecondActivityFunction = () =>
  {
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Second');

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

       <Button onPress = { this.OpenSecondActivityFunction } title = 'Open Second Activity'/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


 class SecondActivity extends Component
{
  static navigationOptions =
  {
     title: 'SecondActivity',
  };

     OpenThirdActivityFunction = () =>
  {
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Third');

  }

  render()
  {
     return(


            <View style={{  flex: 1}}>
            <ListComponents data={alapinCtrl} OpenThirdActivityFunction={this.OpenThirdActivityFunction} />
        </View>

     );
  }
}





 class ThirdActivity extends Component
{
  static navigationOptions =
  {
     title: 'ThirdSecondActivity',
  };

  render()
  {
     return(


            <View style={{  flex: 1}}>

             <Text>3</Text>

        </View>

     );
  }
}


export default ActivityProject = StackNavigator(
{
  First: { screen: App },

  Second: { screen: SecondActivity },

  Third: { screen: ThirdActivity }
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({


  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },ActivityNameTextCss:
  {
     fontSize: 22,
     color: 'black',
     textAlign: 'center',
  },

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ActivityProject', () => ActivityProject);
```

ListComponent.js

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {AppRegistry,View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator} from "react-native";
    import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";


    class ListComponents extends Component {
      constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
          loading: false,
          data: [],
          page: 1,
          seed: 1,
          error: null,
          refreshing: false
        };
      }


       renderSeparator = () => {
        return (
          <View
            style={{
              height: 1,
              width: "98%",
              backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
              marginLeft: "2%"
            }}
          />
        );
      };

      renderHeader = () => {
        return <SearchBar placeholder="Type Here..." lightTheme round />;
      };

      renderFooter = () => {
        if (!this.state.loading) return null;

        return (
          <View
            style={{
              paddingVertical: 20,
              borderTopWidth: 1,
              borderColor: "#CED0CE"
            }}
          >
            <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
          </View>
        );
      };

        render()  {
            return (

            <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
            <FlatList 
                data={this.props.data}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <ListItem
                    roundAvatar
                    title={`${item.name}`}
                    subtitle={item.coders}

                    containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}

  onPress={() => this.props.OpenThirdActivityFunction(item.coders)}
                />
                )}
                keyExtractor={item => item.coders} 
                ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
                ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
                ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
            />
            </List> 
            );
        }
      }


     export default ListComponents;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackNavigator through Component gives undefined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457706/stacknavigator-through-component-gives-undefined-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `SecondActivity` has the `navigation` prop; you need to explicitly pass it to child component:

```
<ListComponent navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Alternatively,

```
<ListComponent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Third')} />;
```

Then just do `<Button onPress={this.props.onPress}` in your `ListComponent`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this will not work, my friend. I've updated the ListComponent.js file. The ListComponent.js file is actually a list. Please can you look again. ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No No riwu. Thank you. It's worked your code. But my ListComponent.js updated. You see it updated OnPress method in ListComponent.js ?

Comment: 1. you cannot comment out JSX with `//`, remove the line completely. 2. try `onPress={() => this.OpenThirdActivityFunction(item.coders)}`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jbma99 This error show  OnPress Method on click. Ah.

Comment: Didn't realise you moved `OpenThirdActivityFunction` to parent component. You need to pass the action to the component as prop `<ListComponent OpenThirdActivityFunction={this. OpenThirdActivityFunction}`, then call `onPress={() => this.props. OpenThirdActivityFunction(item.coders)}`.

Comment: Code add please. I added code. But not working.  onPress={() => this.props.OpenThirdActivityFunction(item.coders)} .    and  case 1:
        return (
          <View >
            <ListComponents data={alapinCtrl} OpenThirdActivityFunction={this.OpenThirdActivityFunction} />
           
          </View>
          );   and .   
  OpenThirdActivityFunction(coders)
  {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Third');
  }

Comment: It's really hard to deal with novices.Yeah. It's me. :) Sorry.

Comment: can you update the code on your original post, and tell me in what way it's not working (errors or `OpenThirdActivityFunction` not called?)

Comment: Hi riwu. Code updated now. Please see you again. Error this -> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: Any errors? Can you add logging to `OpenThirdActivityFunction` to see if it's being called?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jbnn4f . Console.Log added OpenThirdActivityFunction. It's on click work. But show errors.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://snack.expo.io/r1McIKXaf. Can you replicate it on https://snack.expo.io?

Comment: Good morning riwu. https://snack.expo.io/r1FjmQ46M . Mmmm. It's worked man. Thanks to you who never gave up. You did it. Thank man. You're an example to me.

Comment: Riwu. How to get data ThirdActivityPage to OnPress Methods. How to print third page item.coders data. ?

Comment: Just add the parameter in `OpenThirdActivityFunction`, see https://snack.expo.io/HJDYjVN6M

Comment: I added parameter but ThirdActivity Blank page show ? https://snack.expo.io/BJc0HrVTf

Comment: You need to access it with `this.props.navigation.state.params.deneme`. Refer to https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params.html

Comment: this.props.navigation.state.params.data with problem solved. Thanks riwu for everything.

Comment: Hi riwu. 
 
I could not filter out the elements in the list. There were many issues on the site, but I had difficulty understanding them. Please help.https://snack.expo.io/BJc0HrVTf