# [[ERROR]] undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.push')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Guys I'm with this problem and I can't solve it, I try many things but this error apears to me. So I'm lost, please help me

this in the main ( Route) : App.js

```
const Router = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {screen: LoginScreen},
    Julia: {screen: JuliaScreen},
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
)
```

LoginScreen.js --> The Login Screen

```
          <View style = {styles.formContainer}>

              <LoginForm/>

          </View>
```

LoginForm.js --> Component of Login ( Login Form )

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';


import JuliaScreen from './JuliaScreen'

    export default class LoginForm extends Component {
      render() {
        return (

          <View style = {styles.container}>

            <StatusBar 
              barStyle = "light-content" 
            />

            <TextInput 

                onChangeText = {(username) => this.setState({username})}
                value = {this.state.username}
            />
            <TextInput 

                ref = {(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
                onChangeText = {(password) => this.setState({password})}
                value = {this.state.password}
            />

            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {  () => {this.props.navigation.push('Julia')} } style = {styles.btnContainer}>
                <Text style = {styles.btnText}>LOGIN</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>    
          </View>
        );
      }
```

Comment: It should be StackNavigator not createStackNavigator

Comment: This isn't the problem, I try this too but have the same error

Comment: try this.props.navigation.navigate instead of push

Comment: see this:https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/usage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackNavigator through Component gives undefined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457706/stacknavigator-through-component-gives-undefined-error)

Answer (score 0):

As per your `Router` declaration, `LoginForm` is not part of `navigator` and it will not have any reference to `navigation` object. One way is to pass the `navigation` object while you are rendering `LoginForm` in `LoginScreen` component, like

```
<LoginForm navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

But this approach is **not good**. There is another better way to make `navigation` object available for components that are not part of `navigator`. The function is `withNavigation`. Take a look at the official document [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html)

All you need is wrap the `LoginForm` component inside `withNavigation`, like

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
...
class LoginForm extends ... {
    ...
}
export default withNavigation(LoginForm);
```

Hope this will help!