# React navigation this.props.navigation undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a custom header like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Header, Left, Right, } from 'native-base';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class MainHeader extends React.Component {

pressSearch() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
}
render () {
    return(
        <Header style={{paddingTop:25}}>
            <Left style={{marginBottom:10}}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                        <Image
                            style={styles.stretch}
                            source={require('../images/logoforplay.png')}
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.headerText} > Eventlinn </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Left>
            <Right>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.headerButton}
                    onPress={this.pressSearch.bind(this)}
                >
                    <Icon
                        name={'search'}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.headerButton}
                >
                    <Icon
                        name={'add-location'}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.headerButton}
                >
                    <Icon
                        name={'notifications'}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Right>
        </Header>


      )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    mainContainer: {
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'white'
    },
    cardContainer: {
        flex:1
    },
    stretch: {
        height:35,
        width:35,
    },
    headerText: {
        fontSize:24,
        marginTop:3,
    },
    headerButton: {
        marginBottom:10,
        marginLeft:15
    }
})
```

My problem navigation.navigate not working.My routers working well because i can navigate to 'login' with another screen.I read something about pure components but still dont understand how to solve this problem.What do you suggest ? By the way i am new to react native.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackNavigator through Component gives undefined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457706/stacknavigator-through-component-gives-undefined-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';` at the top and then `export default withNavigation(FilmItem);` at the end.

See doc : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 1):

If your header isn't a route within your Router at the head of your app you will need to use withRouter from react-router

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'
export default withNavigation(MainHeader)
```

Now you should be able to access this.props.navigation without directly passing it down as a prop from a parent component.

Comment: i tried withNavigation i think these are same thing but still not working

Comment: whoops! I read react not react-native you need withNavigation from react-navigation

Comment: well i miss to delete export default from class now its working thanks a lot