# Undefined is not an object this.props.navigation - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this issue, don't know if the it's related to navigator options or in render views, can someone please take a look at my code and give some insights.

**APPNavigator.js**

```
export default createSwitchNavigator({
    Main: MainTabNavigator,
    Custom: CustomNavigator,
},{
    initialRouteName: 'Main' 
}
);
```

**CustomNavigator.js**

```
const BrowserStack = createStackNavigator({ Select: Search, Browser: Browser });

export default createStackNavigator({
BrowserStack
},{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }
}
);
```

**MainTabNavigator.js**

```
const DashStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: Dashboard,
});

const SearchStack = createStackNavigator({
  Select: Search,
});

const FavoritesStack = createStackNavigator({
  Auth: Favorites,
});

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  DashStack,
  SearchStack,
  FavoritesStack,
});
```

I run an API call on Search screen and render items on a flatList like so:

```
 <FlatList
  data={this.props.results}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (

    <RkCard rkType='story'>
      <RkButton rkType='small outline' onPress={this.test}>View</RkButton>
    </RkCard>

  )}/>
```

My code breaks in this `test` function, I don't know why I cannot navigate to that screen. I also need to send `item.href` to access later on it.

```
test() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Browser',{ source: item.href })
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access **class props** you need to bind the function to it.

The simplest way would be to use arrow function as

```
test = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Browser',{ source: item.href })
}
```

If the screen is *not registered in the navigation stack*, then you need to add a **HOC** [withNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html#docsNav), which will give access to the navigation props.

Comment: Not solving the issue

Comment: Yes I guess it has to do with something else

Comment: One more thing, is your Search Screen bound to navigation stack?

Comment: How can I tell? sorry I'm really amateur. Inside search screen there's another component Results, and in that one I'm trying to navigate but it's displayed on search screen. It's working on other screens

Comment: The screen in which you render the `Flatlist` should be registered in navigation stacks that you've registered in some way or the other , otherwise you would need to use an hoc as mentioned [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html#docsNav)

Comment: Thanks it's working! now it execute each time the flatList render

Comment: if you add the withNavigation thing to your question I'll accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you show `<FlatList>` in other component you should set navigation props.

Like this:

```
<YourComponent
   results = {...}
   navigation = {this.props.navigation}    //  <-- add this line
>
```

and in YourComponent:

```
<FlatList
  data={this.props.results}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (

    <RkCard rkType='story'>
      <RkButton rkType='small outline' onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Browser')}>View</RkButton>
    </RkCard>

  )}/>
```

Comment: If navigation is used in a component you should do like export default withNavigation(myComponent)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for taking the time

Comment: If it is possible, please confirm the question :) @Youssef