# Accessing parent callback function in nested child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a globally accessible modal by implementing this modal in a top-level component in React Native. To achieve this, I try to extend SwitchNavigator (based on this [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html)) with a callback function and make this accessible through navigation props, but the callback seems to be inaccessible from child components. How can I make the callback accessible from all child components?

My current navigation structure can be illustrated as follows (let's say I try to access the callback from Leaf Component):

- ExtendedSwitchNavigator

  - MyTabNavigator

    - Stack Navigator (Tab 1)

      - **Leaf Component**
    - Tab 2
    - Tab 3
  - OtherComponent

The snippet below shows my current logic.

In App.js:

```
const SwitchNavigatorComponent = createSwitchNavigator({
  TabNavigator: MyTabNavigator,
  OtherComponent: MyOtherComponent
})

// Extending the Switch Navigator component 
class ExtendedSwitchNavigator extends Component {
  static router = SwitchNavigatorComponent.router;
  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
      modalVisible: false
    })
  }
  presentModal = (status) => {
      this.setState({modalVisible: {status}});
  }
  render(){
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return(
      <SwitchNavigatorComponent
      navigation={navigation}
      presentModal={this.presentModal} />

     ... (conditionally render modal)
    )
  }
}

const App = createAppContainer(ExtendedSwitchNavigator);
export default App;
```

Leaf Component:

```
export default class LeafComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      console.log(this.props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.presentModal(true);
  }
}
```

When trying to access the callback with `this.props.presentModal(true)`, I get the error

> this.props.presentModal is not a function. (In 'this.props.presentModal(true)', 'this.props.presentModal' is undefined)

When I print `props` in the leaf component's constructor, I get

```
 Object {
   "navigation": Object {
     "actions": Object {
       "dismiss": [Function dismiss],
       "goBack": [Function goBack],
       "navigate": [Function navigate],
       "pop": [Function pop],
       "popToTop": [Function popToTop],
       "push": [Function push],
       "replace": [Function replace],
       "reset": [Function reset],
       "setParams": [Function setParams],
     },
     "addListener": [Function addListener],
     "dangerouslyGetParent": [Function anonymous],
     "dismiss": [Function anonymous],
     "dispatch": [Function anonymous],
     "emit": [Function emit],
     "getChildNavigation": [Function getChildNavigation],
     "getParam": [Function anonymous],
     "getScreenProps": [Function anonymous],
     "goBack": [Function anonymous],
     "isFocused": [Function isFocused],
     "navigate": [Function anonymous],
     "pop": [Function anonymous],
     "popToTop": [Function anonymous],
     "push": [Function anonymous],
     "replace": [Function anonymous],
     "reset": [Function anonymous],
     "router": undefined,
     "setParams": [Function anonymous],
     "state": Object {
       "key": "...",
       "routeName": "Leaf1",
     },
   },
   "screenProps": undefined,
 }
```

which does not contain anything about presentModal.

[UPDATE]
As per @Gaël S' request, here are the components between ExtendedSwitchNavigator and Leaf.

```
const Tab1StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  LeafComponent: LeafComponent
})

const MyTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Tab1: Tab1StackNavigator,
  Tab2: Tab2Screen,
  Tab3: Tab3Screen
  })
```

Comment: Could you show the components between `ExtendedSwitchNavigator` and `Leaf` ?

Comment: The question is now updated with MyTabNavigator and Tab1StackNavigator, @GaëlS

Comment: withNavigation may help u, checkout this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51333660/2849146

Answer (score 0):

You can use `screenProps` to pass down properties to all screens:

```
<SwitchNavigatorComponent
  navigation={navigation}
  screenProps={{presentModal: this.presentModal}} />
```

Then each screen can access the modal through `this.props.screenProps.presentModal`.

See the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props) for more details