# How can a TabNavigator child screen refer to parent StackNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-props, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

i am trying to navigate from child tab navigator to a screen of parent stack navigator. But this.props.navigation.navigate can only navigate to child's navigation props
'

```
//stack.js

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    DetailPage: DetailPage, //Screen A
    MainScreen: { .        //Screen B
        screen: MainScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    }
    {
        initialRouteName: "MainScreen"
    }
}


//MainScreen.js

<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <TabScreen />
</View>

//TabScreen.js

const TabScreen = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Home: { 
        screen: HomeStack 
    },
    // Videos: { screen: Videos },
    Videos: {
        screen: Videos 
    },
    Shows: {
        screen: AllShows
    },
    Live: { 
        screen: Live
    }
})'
```

I want to navigate from (TabNavigator)TabScreen's Home to (StackNavigator)AppNavigator's DetailPage. But OnPress does Nothing. However, it can navigate to different screens of TabNavigator(child navigator).
Please help me how can I navigate from child TabNavigator to Parent StackNavigator

Comment: this may help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51333660/2849146

Comment: what about the following answer by Victor. He says you can't do that

Comment: you may need some deep dive in navigation, as victor says, navigation has only one root navigation, withNavigation helps to navigate from inner Child Componets to any screen, below link may help. https://www.reactnativeschool.com/complex-navigation-example-with-react-navigation

Comment: @Adarsh withNavigation only binds the navigation prop to the component. But that doesn't mean root navigator knows about TopNavigator

Comment: Try `this.props.navigation.getParent`: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#getparent

Answer (score 1):

Nope. you cant do something like this. You need to make sure there is only one navigator defined. If not, need to make sure the navigation state is connected so that navigators know each other. I would strongly suggest you use a single root navigation

Refer [**Common Mistakes** in react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html)

Explicitly rendering more than one navigator
Most apps should only ever render one navigator inside of a React component, and this is usually somewhere near the root component of your app. This is a little bit counter-intuitive at first but it's important for the architecture of React Navigation.

You need to define everything in a single place (root). Like follows

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";

import Camera from "./screens/camera";
import Welcome from "./screens/welcome";

import Scanner from "./screens/scanner";
import Cards from ".//screens/cards";

const BottomNavigation = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Scan: { screen: Scanner },
    Cards: { screen: Cards },
    Settings: { screen: Cards }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Scan",
    shifting: true
  }
);
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Welcome: {
    screen: Welcome,
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
  },
  Camera: {
    screen: Camera,
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
  },
  Home: {
    screen: BottomNavigation,
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Now i believe you can navigate to different screens as everything is defined on a single navigator.

Comment: what about 'withNavigation' as mentioned in the above comment by Adarsh

Comment: you can get the navigation prop using withNavigation but it will not work as the root navigator is unaware about the MaterialTopNavigator

Comment: my problem is a little different , i want to show a view container above the tabs as header and a view container as a footer. How can i do with only one navigator? Due to which i made a new screen called main screen which has a structure like this
(Top) Header
(Middle) TabNavigator
(Bottom)  Footer

Comment: for header u can use navigationOptions header for TabNavigator .. for footer u need to do something like rendering footer outside of navigator

Comment: thanx, that can work.
Just need a little help , can you give me some example of rendering footer outside navigator. i'm a newbie here

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```js
//stack.js

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    DetailPage: DetailPage, //Screen A
    MainScreen: { .        //Screen B
        screen: MainScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
    TabScreen : {
       screen : TabScreen
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "TabScreen"
    }
}




//TabScreen.js

const TabScreen = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Home: { 
        screen: HomeStack 
    },
    // Videos: { screen: Videos },
    Videos: {
        screen: Videos 
    },
    Shows: {
        screen: AllShows
    },
    Live: { 
        screen: Live
    }
},
    {
        initialRouteName: "Home"
    }
)'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().navigate('routeName', {});
```

---

Also, if you are ready to refactor some code you can create a new Screen and create some extra components, you can create a MainTabScreen for each TabNavigation screen, then:-

App.js

```html
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false
    }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen 
      name="login" 
      component={LogIn} 
      options={{title : 'LOG IN', headerShown: true}}
    />
    <Stack.Screen 
      name="client-tabs-main" 
      component={ClientTabsMain} 
    />
    ... Other Screens ...
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

ClientsTabMain.jsx

```html
<Tabs.Navigator 
    activeColor='white'
    barStyle={{backgroundColor: colors.primary}}

    >
    <Tabs.Screen
    name="home-tabs"
    component={HomeTab}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home-outline" color={color}  size={18} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tabs.Screen
    name="portfolio-tabs"
    component={PortfolioTab}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Portfolio',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="clock" color={color}  size={18} />
      )
    }}

  />
  ... Other Screens ...
</Tabs.Navigator>
```

PortfolioTabs.jsx

```html
<PortfolioStack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: true
  }}
>
<PortfolioStack.Screen 
  name="portfolio" 
  component={Portfolio} 
  options={{
    title: 'Portfolio'
  }}
  />
  <PortfolioStack.Screen 
    name="transaction" 
    component={Transaction} 
  />
</PortfolioStack.Navigator>
```

And navigate using :-

```
this.props.navigation.replace('client-tabs-main',{
      screen: 'portfolio-tabs',
      params: {
        screen: 'portfolio'
      }
    });
```

Comment: As @ThaJay notes, while it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s far more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and help new developers understand the underlying concepts. That's _especially_ true when answering old questions with existing answers; in that case, it's useful to highlight what differentiates your approach from existing answers. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Answer (score -1):

```
createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeTab: {
        screen: HomeStack,
            navigationOptions: {
            title: "Home",
            tabBarOnPress: this.handleTabPress
        }
    },
MessagingTab: {
        screen: MessagingStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Messaging",
            tabBarOnPress: this.handleTabPress
        }
    }
});

handleTabPress = ({ navigation }) => {
    navigation.popToTop();
    navigation.navigate(navigation.state.routeName);
}`
```